# Who's a dwarf gonna call?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I've got a couple of ghosts. And they are attacking one of the vampires I have walled away for safety sake (we don't have the heart to kill them, they were once our friends). What can I do to get rid of the ghosts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to settle a ghost is to inter the corpse. But what if the body has been destroyed or is inaccessible?

Introducing: [SLABS](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Slabs)!

Making slabs is a two-step process. First, get a mason to make a blank slab at a Mason's Workshop. Second, get an Engraver to carve a slab at a Craftsdwarf's workshop.

Finally, build the slab just as you would a grave.

As long as it remains standing (and it should, unless something crazy, like Magma, intervenes) the ghost will remain placated, and bother your dwarves no more.